# Redirect to a part of the same html document

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have a problem with my phonegap app. I have a navigator bar with four titles and for each title i show a part of the same html document. In the last title i have a buttom wich save the data added in the four titles, but i have some required fields in the second title and i want to show a alert when the user trying to push the buttom to save the data and this fields are empty. I want to show an alert message when this happens, and after i want to redirect to the second title of the navigator bar automatically (that it´s a part of the same html document), where the users must complete the required fields. The problem is that i dont know how i can redirect to this form, because i know how to redirect to another html document with the comand "window.location.href('document.html');" but does not work to redirect to a part of the same html document.

I put here some pieces of my code:

The code of the navigator bar is:

```
<div data-role="tabs" id="tabs">

    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#one" data-ajax="false">Title 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#two" data-ajax="false">Title 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#three" data-ajax="false">Title 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#four" data-ajax="false">Title 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

      <div id="one" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
        ...
     </div>
             <div id="two" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
        ...
            </div>
    <div id="three" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="four" class="ui-body-d ui-content">
        ...
    </div>
```

And the code of the buttom is:

```
<input type="button" id="btnSave" name="btnSave" data-icon="star" data-theme="a" data-  form="ui-btn-up-a" class=" ui-btn ui-btn-a ui-icon-star ui-btn-icon-left ui-shadow ui-corner-all" value="Save and end"/>
```

the code of the function javascript called with the buttom is:

```
$("#btnSave").on("click", function(){         
    if($("#fieldHeight").val() == "" || $("#fieldHeight").val() == null){
    confirm("You must introduce your height to continue.");
    window.location.href = 'index.html#two';

    }else if($("#fieldWeight").val() == "" || $("#fieldWeight").val() == null){
    alert("You must introduce your wheight to continue.");
    }else if($("#fieldAge").val() == "" || $("#fieldAge").val() == null){
    alert("You must introduce your age to continue.");
    }else if(gend1.Gender == undefined){
    alert("You must introduce your gender to continue.");
    }else{...
 }
 }
```

The problem is when i use "window.location.href = 'index.html#two';" the app doesnt redirect to the second title but its ok when i put only "window.location.href = 'index.html';" but in this case the app redirect to the first title. Furthermore there is a very big delay between i push the buttom and the app redirect.

I hope that someone can help me and tell me where is the problem or give me one solution. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to same html, use below code

```
$.mobile.changePage("index.html#two");
```

Comment: This code is deprecated as of JQuery Mobile 1.4.0, and i´m using JQuery Mobile 1.9.1. Thanks!!